# Set static IP, network service will no longer boot

Tags: networking, centos

I set a static IP for my CentOS 7 server using `nmtui edit` (edited Wired connection 1):

[image]

and now the network service (`systemctl restart network`) no longer boots.

Log output:

```
-- Unit network.service has begun starting up.
May 03 21:52:09 NIXSERVER NetworkManager[1010]: <info>  [1588557129.6050] ifcfg-rh: update /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-Wired_connection_1 (d8fac711-9114-32c9-a759-05fdeed28a6f,"Wired connection 1")
May 03 21:52:09 NIXSERVER NetworkManager[1010]: <warn>  [1588557129.6094] ifcfg-rh: loading "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0" fails: File '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0' had neither TYPE nor DEVICE keys.
May 03 21:52:10 NIXSERVER network[12774]: Bringing up loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
May 03 21:52:10 NIXSERVER network[12774]: Bringing up interface Wired_connection_1:  [  OK  ]
May 03 21:52:10 NIXSERVER NetworkManager[1010]: <info>  [1588557130.9329] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="08e23dbd-9817-4247-98f3-4a149eecd390" name="enp0s25" result="fail" reason="No suitable device found for this connection."
May 03 21:52:10 NIXSERVER network[12774]: Bringing up interface enp0s25:  Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection.
May 03 21:52:10 NIXSERVER network[12774]: [FAILED]
May 03 21:52:11 NIXSERVER NetworkManager[1010]: <warn>  [1588557131.1644] ifcfg-rh: loading "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0" fails: File '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0' had neither TYPE nor DEVICE keys.
May 03 21:52:11 NIXSERVER network[12774]: Bringing up interface eth0:  Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0'
May 03 21:52:11 NIXSERVER NetworkManager[1010]: <warn>  [1588557131.3840] ifcfg-rh: loading "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0" fails: File '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0' had neither TYPE nor DEVICE keys.
May 03 21:52:11 NIXSERVER network[12774]: Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0'
May 03 21:52:11 NIXSERVER network[12774]: ERROR    : [/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth] Device  does not seem to be present, delaying initialization.
May 03 21:52:11 NIXSERVER /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth[13057]: Device  does not seem to be present, delaying initialization.
May 03 21:52:11 NIXSERVER network[12774]: [FAILED]
May 03 21:52:11 NIXSERVER network[12774]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
May 03 21:52:11 NIXSERVER network[12774]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
May 03 21:52:11 NIXSERVER network[12774]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
May 03 21:52:11 NIXSERVER network[12774]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
May 03 21:52:11 NIXSERVER network[12774]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
May 03 21:52:11 NIXSERVER network[12774]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
May 03 21:52:11 NIXSERVER network[12774]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
May 03 21:52:11 NIXSERVER network[12774]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
May 03 21:52:11 NIXSERVER network[12774]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
May 03 21:52:11 NIXSERVER systemd[1]: network.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 03 21:52:11 NIXSERVER systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.
-- Subject: Unit network.service has failed
```

Is there anything I am missing? This hardware only has one ethernet connected to it.

Command output for `nmcli -p dev`:

```
nmcli -p dev
====================================================
                 Status of devices
====================================================
DEVICE   TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION
----------------------------------------------------
docker0  bridge    connected    docker0
enp12s0  ethernet  connected    Wired connection 1
enp11s0  ethernet  unavailable  --
lo       loopback  unmanaged    --
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logs show enp0s25 and eth0, neither of which show on your nmcli list. Are you sure your edited connections are right?

I wouldn't mess with editing kernel parameters but would rather chase down and fix why the names are wrong.

Are the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts file correctly named and contents correct? The names should correspond with your interface: ifcfg-enp12s0 and DEVICE=enp12s0. If nothing else there looks out of place `systemctl restart NetworkManager` and check.

On my Centos 7 server filename, DEVICE=, nmcli and nmtui all show the same thing - you shouldn't have 3 entries with only one network card. I would remove 2 and fix one. Perhaps you changed out the network card or bios settings leading Centos to rename it. The other 2 generic entries were probably added inadvertently.

Comment: I edited "Wired Connection 1" in nmtui, which is the active connection. As far as I understand it, this is correct. See image in OP I added.

Comment: `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-Wired_connection_1` looks named right to me, and has the data in it I expect. The log indicates it found it okay.

Comment: Huh. Why would nmtui name it ifcfg-Wired_connection_1?

Comment: Yes, fixing that one and removing the nonexistent ones seems to have resolved the errors.

Comment: Excellent. Comments migrated to main answer. You can mark it solved.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to start `eth0`, but your device name is `enp12s0`.

You can set `biosdevname=0 net.ifnames=0` on the kernel commandline to have the old NIC names.